# CPAN/gem-like repository for Objective-C and Cocoa?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa

Is there any centralized repository of useful Objective-C / Cocoa libraries as there is for Perl, Ruby, Python, etc.?

In building my first iPhone app, I'm finding myself implementing some very basic functions that would be just a quick "gem install" away in Ruby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately not :(
There are some very useful sites however.  I find one of the best is [cocoadev.com](http://www.cocoadev.com/) as it contains lots of useful information about many of the more obscure classes usually including snippets of code to do some really cool things :)
Maybe we (the cocoa community) should look into building something like this!

Oh and I just remembered this site [cocoadevcentral.com](http://www.cocoadevcentral.com/) which is also very good for starting out with cocoa.

Answer (score 5):

There's a project for that! It's called **CocoaPods**!

Homepage: http://cocoapods.org/

Source: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods

Answer (score 3):

Daniel mentioned http://cocoadev.com.

More specifically, check out http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?ObjectLibrary.

"This page is for tracking re-usable Cocoa classes that can be mixed, matched, and dropped fairly easily into existing Cocoa projects to add useful functionality."

Answer (score 1):

I'd be interested in what kind of "basic functions" you're having to implement. There's actually quite a lot already there in the provided libraries, and I wonder if you're just not finding functionality that's already there...

Comment: Of course almost everything has a C library somewhere.  Nice pre-ported, iPhone-friendly Objective-C wrappers for some C libs would be useful.  For example, I want to post a multi-part multi-file body to an upload CGI script.  MIME body construction (and parsing) would be useful.

Comment: I guess I wouldn't consider that a "basic" function, and it doesn't surprise me that Ruby libraries for interacting with Web services are easier to find than Objective-C ones. I wonder if WebKit addresses any of this?

Answer (score 1):

There's a new index of reusable code for Mac OS and iOS: [Cocoa Objects](http://cocoaobjects.com)

Answer (score 0):

I might be confused or missing something here... But doesn't apple provide all the Foundation / Cocoa / AppKit / CoreAudio / Qtkit / etc libraries that should provide all of the very basic functions you are looking for?

Other than what xcode comes with or is on the apple dev site, there are no centralized repo's for Cocoa.

Comment: I think what Robert is looking for is a central collection of non-standard components and frameworks.  This would allow developers to share cool NSView subclasses and frameworks easily.

Comment: Exactly! Both the code, which I'm sure exists to some degree scattered around, and the infrastructure like a central directory, search functions, easy install (e.g. "gem install"), and versioning which seem to enhance the sharing of that code.  

Maybe this is a vacuum looking to be filled.

Answer (score 0):

Google Code also has some objective C things up.  It depends on what you are looking for...

Answer (score 0):

Also see GitHub, many useful Objective-C projects, especially re iPhone.  See activerecord & cocoaoniguruma, for instance.

http://github.com/search?q=objective-c

http://github.com/search?q=objc

Answer (score 0):

Google has [Google toolbox for mac](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/) which got me started unit testing my iPhone application which was the main thing I found missing.